# ionic 3 no 'access-control-allow-origin' after I updated my ionic cli

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-httpclient, cross-origin-read-blocking, riot-games-api

I am using ionic lastest version. but my project is ionic 3. I am usin a api it's giving me a some game data . so recently works perfectly my code. but when ionic updated console giving me this error for my data apis =

> no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource. origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

how to fix it?

I do some research and find this code. added to ionic.config.json but not working.

```
"proxies": [
{
  "path": "/lol",
  "proxyUrl": "https://tr1.api.riotgames.com"
}
```

and I tried to add this code my config.xml

```
    <access origin="https://tr1.api.riotgames.com" />
    <access Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*" />
```

none of this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the follow imports/npm packages:

- import { Http } from '@angular/http';
- import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Also try adding `&origin=*` to the end of your request.

```
 let request = this.http.get(url + "&origin=*").map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                 //handle data
            });
```